# Android music player notification priority

Tags: android, notifications, audio-player, android-music-player

Currently working on a music player to improve my knowledge on Android development. I'm stuck on the notification for the music player. I've created it using a RemoteView and it works fine, but the only problem is that it doesn't stay at the top of the notification bar. When I get notifications from Skype, Facebook, etc, they end up above the notification. What configuration should I be using for a music player notification when building the notification? This is what I have so far:

```
Tools tools = new Tools();
        Bitmap bm = tools.getAlbumart(this.context,
                Library.getSongs().get(songService.getIndex()).getAlbumID());
        if (bm != null) {
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);
            remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notifcation_img, resized);
        }
        bm.recycle();

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_song_name,
                Library.getSongs().get(songService.getIndex()).getSongName());
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_artist,
                Library.getSongs().get(songService.getIndex()).getArtistName());

        pauseOrPlay(false);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                resultIntent, 0);

        Intent pauseIntent = new Intent("PAUSEORPLAY");
        Intent fastForwardIntent = new Intent("FAST_FORWARD");
        Intent rewindIntent = new Intent("REWIND");

        PendingIntent pause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 11, pauseIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent fastforward = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12, fastForwardIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent rewind = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 13, rewindIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_playpause_img, pause);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_fastforward_img, fastforward);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_rewind_img, rewind);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.playbutton)
                .setDefaults(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0l})
                .setCustomContentView(remoteViews);


        notifManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't following the [documentation for building a media notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html#mediastyle-notifications)?

Comment: No there isn't any reason, thanks for the link. I'll look into it.

Comment: And just for clarification, is anything wrong with my approach? When I create my service to play music, I create a notification that is attached to the service and update the notification every time the service changes songs/plays/etc.

Comment: `MediaStyle` notifications take care of a lot of what you are doing automatically.

Comment: So I have used the MediaStyle notification, but it doesn't seem to put the notification at the top of the notification bar on my S7 Edge. This is the link to the new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427678/mediastyle-notification-priority-for-music-app